# Options for calling sync code

Tags: c#, async-await

I feel like I have read thousands of SO questions and blog posts and MSDN articles about this stuff, but I'm still not "getting" it completely. So please help me out.

At my work, we have an ASP.NET application that HAS to get data from a sync method. I have no control over this method and I have no idea as to how it is implemented.

I have an async controller method that is calling 3 other async services, I can use async "all the way down" (yay!). But this last one is not async and will likely never be. Worse, it takes the longest. I would love to be able to start tasks for all the services, and await them all. From what I have been able to piece together, I have the following options available to me, and I think I understand most of the consequences, but would like confirmation and clarification where necessary.

So, given the method:

```
public async Task<Thing> GetThing()
{
    var task1 = GetProp1Async(); // etc.
    var syncResult = ......

    myThing.Prop1 = await task1;
    myThing.SyncProp = ....... 
    return myThing;
}
```

The options I have for filling in those dots could be:

Option 1:

Just call the method synchronously. This will block my current thread. My other tasks can all be running, and I can await them later, but I am going to block here, inside my async method.

```
var syncResult = GetSyncResult();
```

Option 2:

Use Task.Run().Result. I understand this is not ideal at all, as I will spawn a new thread, while also blocking my original thread, which I think is the worst case here, right? HOWEVER, I will NOT get the deadlock issue, since I'm forcing a
new thread, right?

```
var syncResult = Task.Run(() => GetSyncResult()).Result;
```

Option 3:

I THINK this is the best option? My async code won't block a thread, but I'm still spawning a new thread that will go do sync work. So, this feels like a net-zero gain. I still have 1 thread that's doing stuff, and possibly waiting, but that still may be my best option?

```
var syncResult = await Task.Run(() => GetSyncResult());
```

Option 4:

I still don't understand ConfigureAwait(false), but I could try it. What does this get me? It seems that some posts say "do this in all the places!" Some say "don't do this to avoid deadlocks". Others say, if you do it, do it "all the way down". Well, I have no idea what GetSyncResult() does, so I have no idea if it calls any async stuff behind the scenes (I mean, it probably doesn't, but I don't KNOW for sure). So could that come back to bite me?

```
var syncResult = await Task.Run(() => GetSyncResult()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

So what is my best option here? Did I miss any options? Worse, did I miss the best option?

I know these questions have been asked and answered to death, but, I'm just not getting my dots connected, and I definitely need some help.

Comment: Option 5, build a separate web api that does the synchronous work but your application can call it asynchronously.

Comment: Go with option 1. As you mentioned, you can await your async Tasks afterward; they may be complete by then.
As you've already observed, option 3 seems a bit pointless because you're taking another thread from ASP.net's precious thread pool, and blocking the one you already have. That's worse than zero-gain, it's taken away a thread another request might have been able to use.

Comment: @andrensairr - in option 3, wouldn't I NOT be blocking on the main thread? as Chad Nedziek mentions below, awaiting on the main thread allows it to do other ASP things, even though I am tying up another thread.

Comment: @Crowcoder - Even if I do that, I will STILL have async code that is calling sync code, and I'm looking for the best option to do that.

Comment: @emery.noel, no you won't. Http calls are async so the only synchronous code would be inside the new service. And since each request occupies a thread anyway, that thread could do just that one thing. It might be a good fit for an Azure Function or AWS Labmda. But, I agree, it is not the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options depend a lot on the context of your code.

If your code (GetThing() in your example, which should really be GetThingAsync), is either a classic ASP.NET action or an event handler for a UI application, which based on your answer, I think it is, then you are an important thread, usually limited in number, so it's important that you not block *this particular thread because it's special*.  Option 3 is the best answer here, because it frees up the important thread to let it get back to UI/Web stuff, and shunts the work off to a non-important thread pool thread. But, importantly, re-enters the important context when the expensive work is done so you can do things like access the HttpContext or UI elements.

If your code is in some library others are going to use and it's super important you never block the thread, option 4 is the "right" answer.  As you've said, there are dozens of blog posts on the internet that go in to varying levels of details as to what those do, so I won't repeat them all here, since you've already read them.  It's up to your caller to decide to attempt to renter the important thread context when they call you by calling ConfigureAwait(false) (to not re-enter it), or just awaiting it straight (which will re-enter it).

Option 1 is the easiest and least likely to have some unexpected bug. Unless you are having capacity issues on your ASP.NET application and you know this call is what's doing it, I'd recommend sticking with the simple one.  You can always add complexity later, but bugs in async code can be very painful to track down, so trying to do it the "right" way first instead of the simple way might cost more than it's worth in the end until you know it's really a problem, and not just a theoretical one.

Comment: Thanks Chad. Yes this is a ASP.NET web app, in which my controller eventually calls "GetThing/Async()", and ultimately returns the Thing to the client. I appreciate the info!